# "complete action using" dialog popping up when it shouldn't

Tags: java, android

I have an app that has 2 buttons: one does a calculation, the other launches a website with a browser. When the user clicks on button1, the answers should display. When the user clicks on button2, the browser will direct them to a website. The trouble is: clicking on button1 causess a "Complete action using" dialog to pop up, prompting the user to pick one of 4 things (application, process, etc.). This didn't happen before and is quite odd. The only thing I can think of is maybe a problem with the onclicklistener and button1 doesn't have a new intent so I don't know how this dialog is coming up.

Here is the manifest:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.costaload"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.costaload;

import com.example.costloads.R;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText mile, diesel;
Button button1, button2;
TextView tv, tv2, tv3;
private double x, y, z, costper, gallon, litres, ophours, stopdrive;
CheckBox checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4;
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mile);
checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setOnClickListener(button1onClickListener);
OnClickListener button2onClickListener = null;
button2.setOnClickListener(button2onClickListener);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cpm);
tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gallons);
diesel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.diesel);
}

private OnClickListener button1onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(final View v) {

    x = Double.parseDouble(mile.getText().toString());
    y = Double.parseDouble(diesel.getText().toString());
    if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
        x = x * 2;
    }
    if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
        x = x * 0.62137;
    }
    ophours = 0;
    ophours = (x / 55) + 2;
    if (ophours >= 11) {
        stopdrive = (ophours / 10) - 1;
        if (stopdrive > 1) { // This block isn't closed.
            ophours = ophours + (stopdrive * 10);
        }
        gallon = x / 5.5;
        if (checkBox4.isChecked()) {
            gallon = gallon + (ophours * 1.1);
        }
        if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
            litres = gallon * 3.785;
            tv3.setText(new DecimalFormat("####.##").format(litres)
                    + "L");
        }
        z = (gallon * y) + (x * 0.655);
        costper = z / x;
        tv.setText(format.format(z));
        tv2.setText(format.format(costper) + "/mile");
        tv3.setText(new DecimalFormat("####.##").format(gallon)
                + "gal.");
    }
    ;
};

private OnClickListener button2OnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Url.parse("http://www.ratenroll.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
  };
 };
};
```

Here is the activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="# of miles"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Price of diesel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/diesel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mile"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Visit www.ratenroll.com" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/diesel"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Kilometres (not miles)" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Round trip" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="Litres (not gallons)" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Reefer load" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Compute" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Total Cost"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Cost per mile"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text=" "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cpm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="   "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Fuel required"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gallons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="   "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of adding the same onClickListener to two buttons and using a switch statement to distinguish them is prone to errors.

```
package com.example.costaload;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText mile, diesel;
    Button button1, button2;
    TextView tv, tv2, tv3;
    private double x, y, z, costper, gallon, litres, ophours, stopdrive;
    CheckBox checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4;
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mile);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(button1onClickListener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(button2OnClickListener);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cpm);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gallons);
        diesel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.diesel);
    }

    private OnClickListener button1onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            x = Double.parseDouble(mile.getText().toString());
            y = Double.parseDouble(diesel.getText().toString());
            if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                x = x * 2;
            }

            if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                x = x * 0.62137;
            }

            ophours = 0;
            ophours = (x / 55) + 2;

            if (ophours >= 11) {
                stopdrive = (ophours / 10) - 1;
            }
            if (stopdrive > 1) {
                ophours = ophours + (stopdrive * 10);
            }

            gallon = x / 5.5;

            if (checkBox4.isChecked()) {
                gallon = gallon + (ophours * 1.1);
            }

            if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                litres = gallon * 3.785;
                tv3.setText(new DecimalFormat("####.##").format(litres) + "L");
            }

            z = (gallon * y) + (x * 0.655);
            costper = z / x;
            tv.setText(format.format(z));
            tv2.setText(format.format(costper) + "/mile");
            tv3.setText(new DecimalFormat("####.##").format(gallon) + "gal.");
        }

    };

    private OnClickListener button2OnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.ratenroll.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    };
};
```

I didn't change your xml file.

Good Luck.

Comment: Good point, and it also removes the unease around not having an assert condition in the (missing) default: statement of the switch.

Comment: Hi, I had originally tried using two listeners and saw an example where "case" was used, which looked neater. Eclipse keeps throwing errors like it is totally screwing with me lol. In particular, when I put in my 2nd button listener button2.setOnClickListener(button2onClickListener); I am getting that it can't be resolved to a variable, so Eclipse is making me put in a local variable and then set it to null. Then I am also getting "the value of the field new View.OnClickListener(){}.button2OnClickListener is never used." Why is it giving me such a hard time with this second listener?

Comment: @Jason: Hi, I updated my code and had a look at the XML event thing but got the same hard time trying to implement the 2nd click listener. Started getting weird errors, like Eclipse all of a sudden didn't know what "R" was. Ugh.

Comment: At some point while you were working on the above code you probably got a error that said "expected }" or something similar.  The error showed up way down at the bottom of the page so that's where you added a }.  The problem is that that is not where it really belonged.  If you'll post the complete xml layout and activity class , I will help you sort this out.  Be prepared to spend days at a time looking for a miss placed semi-colon until you become fluent in the language.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, that's exactly what happened. I have posted my xml and the code as it is now.

Comment: @Jason: When I added the button2 listener, Eclipse asked me to set it up as a variable and initialize it but not for button1. What does Eclipse not like about this second button? Thanks for looking.

Comment: You were still having trouble with unclosed code blocks.  ( missing } )  I fixed it for you and updated my answer.  Ran it on the emulator and it seems to be working although I did not check your math.

Comment: @Jason, Hi there, yes, it seems to run on mine except that the button1 worked once and then stopped and button2 has a warning about the value of the new view.OnClickListener for button2 is not used. The warning gives me the option to either remove that button2onclicklistener, put a getter and setter for the listener or suppress that warning. What I don't understand is why it selectively ran once and why the buttons won't work. Now Eclipse is saying that activity_main (along with the other variables) cannot be resolved or are not fields after it forced me to create R.java when I clicked Clean.

Comment: That is a different issue. Do a search for "android importing R" I'm not at my computer now I'm on my mobile.  Let me know what you find out.

Comment: @Jason, sorry for the delay. Thank you for your help. I ended up starting my project again and it works. I'm not sure why Eclipse goes into a downward spiral sometimes lol. It works fine after some futzing.

Answer (score 1):

What's that extra brace doing here?

```
tv3.setText(new DecimalFormat("####.##").format(gallon)+"gal.");
         break;}  // did you mean to do this?
```

Move the brace to after `break;` in the second case statement.

P.S.  Please get into the habit of correctly indenting code and lining up braces.  Also use your IDE's auto code formatting features to keep things tidy.  It will make things a LOT easier for you.

P.P.S.  For other readers.  Why did this even compile as the second case statement is now outside the switch?

Comment: He had an unclosed if statement in the first case that got closed after the first break.  The next brace closed the switch.

Comment: Ah yes, missed that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Simon, I'm wondering why it compiled too because Eclipse puts in all these suggestions and I'm taking for granted that it's right when Eclipse stops complaining. :)